# Difference between BATT and Voltage on multimeter

Tags: voltage, instrument

My digital multimeter (the one in the picture) has a function called "BATT", which, according to the manual, is used to read the voltage of batteries. I noticed that it gives different measurements from the continuous voltage function but the manual does not specify the difference between the two.
[image]

What is the difference between the BATT and the continuous voltage functions?

Comment: It has a lower resistance so the battery reading will mean something. Voltage is a function of load and the discharge level of the battery. A nearly dead battery will show ok voltage in an open circuit measurement. The manual may say more.

Comment: Possibly useful: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/169814/multimeter-battery-test

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the voltmeter mode, the multimeter has a high impedance (usually on the order of $\text{M}\Omega$) in order to "load" or "disturb" the circuit you are measuring as little as possible. However, even almost dead batteries can present a high terminal voltage when measured under no load, so the open-circuit voltage of a battery can be a misleading indicator of how much energy it has left.

The battery test feature normally measures the voltage of the battery under a certain load, i.e. the multimeter presents the battery with a certain resistance (perhaps on the order of $\text{k}\Omega$). The terminal voltage of a near-dead battery will drop to a very low value under load, and so it is a better indicator of capacity. If you have a second meter, you might be able to use that to determine the load resistance that the battery test feature uses.

The battery test feature is not exactly essential and it is not found in many higher-end multimeters, because you can always load the battery with an external resistor and measure its voltage that way.